# JQUERY Toggle and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

I have a menu and a submenu.  Submenu content is loaded with ajax.

The submenu toggles.  The problem is that when I click to hide the submenu it still does the ajax call.

How can I only make it do an ajax call when I click to open the menu?

```
$("#showsubmenu").live("click", function() {
                var attrib = $(this).attr('menuid'); 

                $("#"+attrib).toggle();
                $("#"+attrib).html("<h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading links...</h4>");
                $.ajax({  
                   cache: false,
                   url: "submenu.php", 
                   dataType: "html",
                   data: "&menuid="+attrib,
                   success: function (data) {   
                        $("#"+attrib).html(data);
                        },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }

                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution along with some performance benefit which will not make ajax call once the submenu is populated even when you open it next time. I hope this will help you.

```
$("#showsubmenu").live("click", function() {
                var attrib = $(this).attr('menuid'); 
                var $attrib = $("#"+attrib);

                $attrib.toggle();

                if(!$attrib.data("subMenuPopulated") && $attrib.is(":visible")){

                    $attrib.html("<h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading links...</h4>");
                    $.ajax({  
                     cache: false,
                     url: "submenu.php", 
                     dataType: "html",
                     data: "&menuid="+attrib,
                     success: function (data) {   
                        $attrib.html(data).data("subMenuPopulated", true);
                      },
                      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                      }
                    });
                 }

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done it in the past by adding/removing a class.

Add a test like

```
if( !$(this).hasClass("submenu-loaded") ) {        
    ...Ajax call
}
```

Then in the success handler, use .addClass("submenu-loaded") to prevent the Ajax call being made again.

Comment: i tried this and it worked. Thanks!  What if i I want it to reload every time the menu is open?

Comment: You can use .toggleClass("submenu-loaded") instead, which will add the class if it's not there and remove it if it's not there (but you'll have to do it outside the Ajax call). Alternatively, you could add an 'else { $(this).removeClass("submenu-loaded"); }' to the above if() test. The point is to remove the class if it's not there, add it if it isn't (and make the Ajax call).

Comment: Oh, and feel free to accept/vote up the answer if you like it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

since a `.toggle()` changes the visibility of the object, you could check against it's CSS display property. If it's not hidden already, then there's no need to start the Ajax-Call.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#"+attrib).not(':visible')) {
    ...run ajax code
}
```

This is just checking to see if the sub-menu is visible, if it is not then you can execute the ajax code.

Or if you want to check for the existence of the code within the sub-menu you can do something like:

```
if ($("#"+attrib).html().length == 0) {
    ...run ajax code
}
```

This code checks for any html within the sub-menu, if none is found the ajax code can be run.